# What is the difference between R.style.x, and R.attr.x?

Tags: android, android-styles

What is the difference between let's say `android.R.style.TextAppearance_large` and `android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attr part is just a *thing* which can been styled e.g. with a theme while that style is already one defined style.

So you can refer a style without knowing the style attributes. That is really helpful if you want to define a control which can been styled in multiple ways. Like for a button you have a holo style or some other device typical styles.

If you know C you can compair it with a prototype (or header file) while the style is the implementation.